# How to populate data table in Jquery loop

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a data table and response is coming from the API. Now I want to display that information in that data table.
The response is as below

```
[
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": null,
        "count_date": "2018-03-02",
        "bounce_count": "281494",
        "deliver_count": "558350"
    },
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": null,
        "count_date": "2018-03-03",
        "bounce_count": "1",
        "deliver_count": "0"
    },
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": "test.com",
        "count_date": "2018-03-05",
        "bounce_count": "444",
        "deliver_count": "194747"
    },
]
```

I want to populate the above information in a data table so that keys of that json are table headers and values in rows below

Comment: Is every JSON entry going to contain the same key value pairs?

Comment: yes response will be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can use below code to display the Jquery datatables based on your Ajax result.

Assuming that you made an Ajax call and you have your data in result variable (here i have given it as a constant)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result = [
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": null,
        "count_date": "2018-03-02",
        "bounce_count": "281494",
        "deliver_count": "558350"
    },
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": null,
        "count_date": "2018-03-03",
        "bounce_count": "1",
        "deliver_count": "0"
    },
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": "test.com",
        "count_date": "2018-03-05",
        "bounce_count": "444",
        "deliver_count": "194747"
    },
]
  LoadCurrentData(result)
    
} );

function LoadCurrentData(result) {
    var example = $("#example")
 // "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
   //     "domain": "test.com",
     //   "count_date": "2018-03-05",
       // "bounce_count": "444",
      //  "deliver_count": "194747"
    example.DataTable ({ 
        "data" : result,
        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "server_id"},
            { "data" : "domain" },
            { "data" : "count_date" },
            { "data" : "bounce_count" },
            { "data" : "deliver_count" }
        ]
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Server_id</th>
                <th>domain</th>
                <th>count_date</th> 
                <th>bounce_count</th>
                <th>deliver_count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: I am seeing this error
DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'server_id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: in that case, please post your code so that we can check what's going different with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the "shape" of your data you can do something like this:

```
var data = [{
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": null,
        "count_date": "2018-03-02",
        "bounce_count": "281494",
        "deliver_count": "558350"
    },
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": null,
        "count_date": "2018-03-03",
        "bounce_count": "1",
        "deliver_count": "0"
    },
    {
        "server_id": "123.123.12.12",
        "domain": "test.com",
        "count_date": "2018-03-05",
        "bounce_count": "444",
        "deliver_count": "194747"
    }
];

var example = null;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    success: function(result) {
        var arr = [],
            cols = [];
        result.reduce(function(pre, item) {
            Object.keys(item).forEach(function(i) {
                if (arr.indexOf(i) === -1) {
                    arr.push(i);
                    cols.push({
                        "data": i,
                        "title": i,
                        "default": ""
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#example")) {
            example.destroy();
            $('#example').empty();
        }
        example = $("#example").DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "columns": cols,
            "data": result,
            "autoWidth": false
        });
    }
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/yfx7rrpw/20/). There are probably more elegant ways of generating the columns array...

And your `ajax` call will likely be different as this is using the mocked `ajax` mechanism of JSFiddle.